# Making an ajax call work if async is true using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have gotten my Ajax call to work using JQuery and making async false.  However, I have read on several blogs that I should use the async nature of Javascript.  What should I do to this Ajax call to get it to work using async?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#new-search').click(function(){
            var userInput = $('#address').val();
            if(!userInput){
                userInput = $('#address').attr('placeholder');
            }
            if(Number(userInput)){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/userprofilepage',
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        val: userInput,
                        field: 'zip_search'
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Job Matcher page has been updated");
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log("Job Matcher page has not been updated");
                        var message = msg["responseJSON"]["val"].toString();
                        message = message.replace('val', 'zip code');
                        showNotify(message, 'error');
                    },
                });
            } else{
                alert("false")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it *not* work?

Comment: @David, if I do not use async: false, the page refreshes with old data, not the new data the user has inputed

Comment: I don't see how this code would be responsible for that.  This is only refreshing the page after a successful response from the server.  It sounds like the problem is related to something else not shown here.

Comment: [success](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) 'A function to be called if the request succeeds' Your page is not reloading due to the `location.reload();` in the `success` function of jqXHR. As @David pointed out its happening because of some other code not shared here. `async`'s value has nothing to do with the execution of `success` but with what is written after `$.ajax()`

Comment: Anyways `async: false` "(and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive."